# Count number of times a specific day\date occurs between two dates

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have prices for a contract which change on the 01st April every year.  The start and end dates of the contract may cross multiple price changes and initially I want to count the changes between the contract start and contract end date.

This is the result set I'm trying to get:

01/04/2017 To 31/03/2018 = 0

31/03/2018 To 01/04/2018 = 1

01/01/2015 To 31/12/2018 = 4

Currently my query looks like this (manual horribleness):

```
SET DATEFORMAT DMY;
SELECT
Contract_ID,
 (Period_1 + Period_2 + Period_3 + Period_4 + Period_5 + Period_6 + Period_7
+ Period_8 + Period_9
 ) AS Split_Count
FROM
(
SELECT 
C.Contract_ID,
 CASE
 WHEN ('01/04/2011'BETWEEN Contract_Date_OLD AND Contract_Date_NEW) THEN 1
 ELSE 0
 END AS Period_1,
 CASE
 WHEN ('01/04/2012'BETWEEN Contract_Date_OLD AND Contract_Date_NEW) THEN 1
 ELSE 0
 END AS Period_2, 
 CASE
 WHEN ('01/04/2013'BETWEEN Contract_Date_OLD AND Contract_Date_NEW) THEN 1
 ELSE 0
 END AS Period_3,
 CASE
 WHEN ('01/04/2014'BETWEEN Contract_Date_OLD AND Contract_Date_NEW) THEN 1
 ELSE 0
 END AS Period_4,
 CASE
 WHEN ('01/04/2015'BETWEEN Contract_Date_OLD AND Contract_Date_NEW) THEN 1
 ELSE 0
 END AS Period_5,
 CASE
 WHEN ('01/04/2016'BETWEEN Contract_Date_OLD AND Contract_Date_NEW) THEN 1
 ELSE 0
 END AS Period_6,
 CASE
 WHEN ('01/04/2016'BETWEEN Contract_Date_OLD AND Contract_Date_NEW) THEN 1
 ELSE 0
 END AS Period_7,
 CASE
 WHEN ('01/04/2017'BETWEEN Contract_Date_OLD AND Contract_Date_NEW) THEN 1
 ELSE 0
 END AS Period_8,
 CASE
 WHEN ('01/04/2018'BETWEEN Contract_Date_OLD AND Contract_Date_NEW) THEN 1
 ELSE 0
 END AS Period_9
FROM Contract C
```

What would be the best way of doing this?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really be helpful.

Comment: The sample data and results are in the result set above the query.  It doesn't have headings but the first date is the start date, the second date is the end date and the number is the number of 01/04/xx dates crossed.  I should have put it in a neat table sorry.

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this using outer apply to join to your period table

```
;with periods as (
    select 1 as [period], '01/04/2011' as startdate
    union all select 2 as [period], '01/04/2012'
    union all select 3 as [period], '01/04/2013'
    union all select 4 as [period], '01/04/2014'
    union all select 5 as [period], '01/04/2015'
    union all select 6 as [period], '01/04/2016'
    union all select 7 as [period], '01/04/2017'
    union all select 8 as [period], '01/04/2018'
    union all select 9 as [period], '01/04/2019'
)
select      *
from        periods
outer apply (   select      Contract_ID
                            , count(*) as Split_Count
                from        Contract
                where       startdate between Contract_Date_OLD and Contract_Date_NEW
                group by    Contract_ID) c
```

you can pivot this data to see the period counts on a single row.

```
select      c.Contract_ID,
            max(case when p.[period] = 1 then c.Split_Count end) as period_1,
            max(case when p.[period] = 2 then c.Split_Count end) as period_2,
            max(case when p.[period] = 3 then c.Split_Count end) as period_3,
            max(case when p.[period] = 4 then c.Split_Count end) as period_4,
            max(case when p.[period] = 5 then c.Split_Count end) as period_5,
            max(case when p.[period] = 6 then c.Split_Count end) as period_6,
            max(case when p.[period] = 7 then c.Split_Count end) as period_7,
            max(case when p.[period] = 8 then c.Split_Count end) as period_8,
            max(case when p.[period] = 9 then c.Split_Count end) as period_9
from        [periods] p
outer apply (   select      Contract_ID
                            , count(*) as Split_Count
                from        Contract
                where       startdate between Contract_Date_OLD and Contract_Date_NEW
                group by    Contract_ID) c
group by    Contract_ID
```

or just get the total sum for the contract.

```
select      c.Contract_ID,
            sum(Split_Count) as Split_Count
outer apply (   select      Contract_ID
                            , count(*) as Split_Count
                from        Contract
                where       startdate between Contract_Date_OLD and Contract_Date_NEW
                group by    Contract_ID) c
group by    Contract_ID
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  The solution I went for in the end was to have a separate Calendar table with a column for the periods.  Subtracting the start period from the end period gives the number of changes.